# Posting a Kibana Dashboard "Publicly"

Tags: kibana, elasticsearch, concrete5

I'm building a data-driven web interface on Concrete5 and utilizing ELK to store (and hopefully visualize) a fairly substantial database. Essentially, each "user" on the site should see a Kibana visualization(s) that are specific to him/her.

The way we're currently looking at doing this (on a very high level) is:

1. User logs into website
2. Website uses dynamic code to call appropriate Kibana visualization based on the currently logged in user.

My questions:

Can I display Kibana visualizations in this way?

Is there a better way to do this (and if so, can you point us in the right direction)

Any advice?

---

Your experience, input, suggestions, or advice are most welcome!

(Versions: Concrete 5.7 and Kibana 4)

Comment: should the dash boards dynamically change based on which user logs in?? is that what u want ??

Comment: @TejusPrasad: That isn't necessary as I've restricted certain pages to certain users already. My new question is on whether or not there is a safer way to put the visualizations onto those pages than iframe.